# Missing a Zero (0) from a parameterised value of type Int32 during Runtime

Tags: c#, int32

I have a function that takes 3 parameters, username(string), password(string) and an ID(Int32) for that i have just passed the parameter like this

```
newresult.dataSet = postCommands.getCustomerBalance("customer1","password1234", "02070481");
```

but the parameter that takes the ID(Int32) takes only the 2070481 after the first 0 from the value passed.
[image]

I just want to know why it is happening and where that Zero (0) have gone ??? what i can do to get the complete value that i have passed as parameter ???

Comment: If you want to see exact "02070481", then it needs to be `string`, not `Int32`. Otherwise - how can you imagine leading zero in integer?

Comment: Plaintext passwords... fail

Comment: @DGibbs yup, But for testing purposes only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's an integer. Integers don't have "leading zeros".  A string formatted from an integer would.

I'd suggest if you need the leading zero, then just format it where you need it displayed like that.